# How to record frames with ffmpeg and finish the recording

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, raspbian, mjpeg

In the following code, i trying to create a class to record frames from an IP camera (RTSP), save frames on a .avi file and finish the record, but, when i kill the operation, the video file may be corrupted. Have any other more safely way to stop the ffmpeg recording?

.cpp file:

```
#include "videorecorder.h"


VideoRecorder::VideoRecorder(const std::string& rtspUrl) :
    url(rtspUrl),
    recording(false)
{

}

VideoRecorder::~VideoRecorder()
{
    end_record();
}

bool VideoRecorder::start_record(const std::string &fileName)
{
    if (recording) {
        std::cerr << "Already recording." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::string command = "ffmpeg -rtsp_transport udp -i " + url
                          + " -c:v mjpeg -preset fast -qp 0 " + fileName;

    videoWriter = popen(command.c_str(), "w");
    if (!videoWriter) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening ffmpeg process." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    recording = true;
    ffmpegProcessId = getpid();
    std::cout << "Recording started." << std::endl;
    return true;
}

bool VideoRecorder::end_record()
{
    if (recording) {
        if (videoWriter) {
            pid_t ffmpegPID = fileno(videoWriter);

            if (kill(ffmpegPID, SIGTERM) == 0) {
                std::cout << "Recording terminated successfully." << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cerr << "Error terminating recording." << std::endl;
                return false;
            }

            int status = pclose(videoWriter);

            if (status == 0) {
                std::cout << "Recording ended successfully." << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cerr << "Error ending recording. pclose status: " << status << std::endl;
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Error ending recording. videoWriter is nullptr." << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        recording = false;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

.h file:

```
#ifndef VIDEORECORDER_H
#define VIDEORECORDER_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <csignal>
#include <sys/wait.h>

extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <unistd.h>
}

#include <linux/videodev2.h>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>


class VideoRecorder
{
public:
    VideoRecorder(const std::string& rtspUrl);
    ~VideoRecorder();
    bool start_record(const std::string& fileName);
    bool end_record();

private:
    std::string url;
    AVFormatContext *formatContext;
    AVStream *videoStream;
    AVCodecContext *codecContext;
    AVCodec *codec;
    SwsContext *swsContext;
    AVFrame *frame;
    AVPacket packet;
    bool recording;
    pid_t ffmpegProcessId;
    FILE* videoWriter;
};

#endif // VIDEORECORDER_H
```

I'm using the ffmpeg lib becouse i need max speed on frames recording, and OpenCV and AV Lib is much slowness than ffmpeg.

This my terminal output after recording during 10 seconds (generated a file with 23 seconds duration):

```
Recording started.
ffmpeg version 4.3.6-0+deb11u1+rpt5 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1+rpt5 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-epoxy --enable-sand --libdir=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu --arch=arm64 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-vout-drm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:[password]@[ip]:[port]/live/0/MAIN':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTSP Server
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.280000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Codec AVOption preset (Configuration preset) specified for output file #0 (/home/guardian-tech/Pictures/output_frame.avi) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Codec AVOption qp (Constant quantization parameter rate control method) specified for output file #0 (/home/guardian-tech/Pictures/output_frame.avi) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, avi, to '/home/guardian-tech/Pictures/output_frame.avi':
  Metadata:
    INAM            : RTSP Server
    ISFT            : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj420p(pc), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
[rtsp @ 0x5592e7bb00] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5592e7bb00] RTP: missed 212 packets
[h264 @ 0x5592ebb790] concealing 2192 DC, 2192 AC, 2192 MV errors in I frame
rtsp://admin:[password]@[ip]:[port]/live/0/MAIN: corrupt decoded frame in stream 0
[rtsp @ 0x5592e7bb00] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5592e7bb00] RTP: missed 6 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5592e7bb00] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5592e7bb00] RTP: missed 14 packets
[h264 @ 0x5592f1bd30] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 42 29
[h264 @ 0x5592f1bd30] error while decoding MB 42 29, bytestream 0
[h264 @ 0x5592f1bd30] concealing 4687 DC, 4687 AC, 4687 MV errors in I frame
rtsp://admin:[password]@[ip]:[port]/live/0/MAIN: corrupt decoded frame in stream 0
Error terminating recording.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [examples](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.3/dir_687bdf86e8e626c2168c3a2d1c125116.html) to learn how to work with ffmpeg.

Basically, what you need for your task is demux the incoming RTSP and mux it to .avi file.

[Remuxing](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.3/remuxing_8c_source.html) example can be helpful for you with this task. Input context for rtsp can be initialized the same way as for files, you can also set "tcp" flag.

```
AVDictionary* options = nullptr;

// Open with tcp
av_dict_set(
  &options,
  "rtsp_transport",
  "tcp",
  0
);

std::string camera_address = "rtsp://put_your_address";

int ret = avformat_open_input(
    &input_format_context,
    camera_address.c_str(),
    nullptr,
    &options
);
```

Dont't forget to write header (*avformat_write_header* function) before writing packets to file. And at the end write trailer (*av_write_trailer* function).